# FreeNAS Flash Drive Corruption

Tags: freebsd, boot, truenas

The flash drive that had FreeNAS on it was unplugged while the system was running.  Now when I start the system, I get the following error:

```
GRUB loading . .
Welcome to GRUB!

error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode . . .
grub rescue> _
```

Here is a snapshot of the drive:

[image]

Comment: How confident are you in your backups?

Comment: Backups of what?

Comment: The data on your flash drive.

Comment: Not very confident.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new FreeNAS flash drive from scratch (not the one you're using).
- Restore you config from backup

You should regularly backup your configuration to prepare for a situation like this. In case you have no backups it's very likely that you can restore the old configuration from the damaged flash drive. In order to do that you import the zpool on the old flash drive on any FreeBSD system. The config file is located at `/data/freenas-v1.db`. You can then restore the config file in the GUI:

*System → General → Upload Config*

Comment: I will test this out this week